# How can I automatically set the orientation of an iPhone subview?

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, uikit

I'm going in circles here.  I have set shouldAutoRotateToInterfaceOrientation for all the view controllers.  My app is running correctly in landscape, like this:[alt text http://img517.imageshack.us/img517/3749/screenshot20100701at802.png](http://img517.imageshack.us/img517/3749/screenshot20100701at802.png)

However, when I add a new subview using `[window addSubview:whatever.view];` it shows up like this:[alt text http://img291.imageshack.us/img291/3749/screenshot20100701at802.png](http://img291.imageshack.us/img291/3749/screenshot20100701at802.png)

How can I make the new subview automatically be added in landscape orientation?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

window is probably not managed by one of your view controllers that implement shouldAutoRotateToInterfaceOrientation.

Add your view to one of your view controllers that implement the autorotation.

Comment: ok now i get: `[viewController addSubview:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance`

thanks for your help.

Comment: i think i'm a little confused on when to use `[viewController view]` and `viewController.view` because one works in some places and not in others...

Comment: viewController is not a UIView, so you cannot add subviews. [viewController view] and viewController.view is the the same, just a different syntax.

Comment: Just do it the same as on the working views. Without code it's hard to look at.